# Fixing dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, dataframe

**Scenario:** I am using a python code to extract data from excel files. Currently my code reads each file into a single data frame and joins them in a list of data frames.

**Issue:** The original excel source files are organized by columns (dates) and identifiers (rows). Some of these files have a date in a string format, such as 20170611 or 11062015.

**What I tried so far:** From previous research here in SO, I found some questions and answers about this topic, but they all referred to a single conversion, for example with:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('24052010', "%d%m%Y").date()
datetime.date(2010, 5, 24)
```

This is the kind of operation I need, but I would like to perform it for all column headers of the affected files in a loop.

**Question:** Is it possible to do this? How can it be done?

**Obs:** I thought about looping through the excel files with some code to select the ones that are affected, but since I don't know how to do that, I will select the files by hand and have them fixed individually. So my objective is just to loop the columns and fix the dates of those files.

**Current code that gets data from excel:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob, os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl


directory = os.path.join("C:\\","Users\\DGMS\\Desktop\\final 2")        

list_of_dfs = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        f = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(f)
        list_of_dfs .append(pd.read_excel(f))
```

Comment: Without any example of your dataFrame, it is not exactly clear what the issue is. The way I understand is the date strings in your excel file are saved in different formats?

Comment: Work with the last digits of every date value, check if it greater than or equal `1900`. If so, that tells you that the format is `%d%m%Y`. Otherwise your format is `%Y%m%d`. That's just my observation from the examples you provided.

Comment: @kwant Thanks for the comment. My source files usually have dates as column headers (ex. 10/12/2017, or 2017-10-12, with some minor differences, but still as a date). In some of the source files, the headers are strings (ex. 20171012, or 12102017). This is for all the column headers in those files, so what I am trying to find is a way to do this as a loop, without referencing each value. Sorry I cannot explain it better than this.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks for the comment. The problem is not just finding out if the string is 20171012 or 12102017, but to be able to change each of those strings column headers) to a date format, such as 2017/10/12 or similar.

Comment: check `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime`. It does a reasonable guess at inferring the datetime format. If all formats with the year at the back have the day (and not the month) first you can use the `dayfirst=True` argument

I also prefer `pathlib.Path.glob` over `os.walk`

I would do something like this

```
from pathlib import Path
start_dir = Path('.')
excel_files  = start_dir.glob('*/*.xlsx')
list_of_dfs = [(filename, pd.read_excel(filename, header=0, dayfirst=True)) for filename in excel_files]

for filename, df in list_of_dfs:
    try:
        datetimes = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
        df.columns = datetimes 
    except ValueError:
        print('failed to parse column in %s' % filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the suggested code, but got a "unknown string format error". Is it possible to convert each column of each dataframe before joining all of them?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? the DataFrames are not joined, the references to them are just kept in a list, just as in your example.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know if its possible to do it directly in each data frame (with no loop), not that I wanted to do it, it is just for the information. And about the error, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: the `to_datetime` raises that `ValueError` when it comes at a string it can not parse correctly. I changed the code a tiny bit to allow you to diagnose this more easily

Comment: Thanks for the modification. But now I get the "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error. Sorry to be pushing this problem, but I am just starting with python.

Comment: did you also modify `list_of_dfs = [(filename, pd.read_excel(filename, header=0, dayfirst=True)) for filename in excel_files]`

Comment: I will change that now. Regarding the usage of pathlib.path.glob, what is the difference to os.walk? And where do I put the path in the first one?

Comment: did you check the documentation? `start_dir = Path("C:\\","Users\\DGMS\\Desktop\\final 2")`

Comment: Thanks, now the code runs with no error. But I now get and empty list of dfs for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse). It might solve your problem, as it can interpret several ways of writing dates.

```
columns = df.columns
rename_cols = {}
for col in columns:
    rename_cols[col] = parse(col)

df.rename(columns=rename_cols, axis=1)
```